# How to automatically hide expanded menu when using anchors?

Tags: menu, anchor

guys. I'm not expert in coding and want to ask you, how to automatically hide expanded menu when using anchors?

https://jsfiddl(e).net/y19wt23m/

Please remove () in link, this service blocks my link. But when i use code here, it writes that my message contains code only and blocks it too.

Thank you in advance!